# "Не дотянем до пенсии". НЕ — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: грамматика, частица-не, глаголы

**Не дотянем до пенсии.** В данном случае пишется слитно или все-таки **не** будет раздельно?
Ведь речь не о качественной неполноценности чего-либо (недотягивает до идеала, недотягивать до уровня).

Answer (score 3):

> Не дотянем до пенсии. В данном случае пишется слитно или все-таки не
>   будет раздельно?

Раздельно. Если смотреть по смыслу, то слитное написание тут исключено.

> Ведь речь не о качественной неполноценности чего-либо (недотягивает до
>   идеала, недотягивать до уровня).

Нет. Здесь именно отрицание глагола "дотянем".
Вы правильно понимаете, что "не до-" (случай глагола с приставкой "до-" и отрицательной частицей) можно отличить "недо-" (случай глагола со сложной приставкой "недо-") можно отличить благодаря тому факту, что во втором случае имеет место неполноценность действия, недостижение, если так можно выразиться, результата.

Но дело то в том, что эта качественная неполноценность возникает тогда и только тогда, когда его можно противопоставить действию незавершенному, не достигшему цели. *"Я не дописал письмо - и не отправил его вовремя" (логическая незавершенность). "Я недописал письмо, допишу позже" (неполноценность).* Вот во втором случае возникает возможность слитного написания - и то факультативная. В вашем же примере этого противопоставления нет. Ни  о какой "неполноценности" действия говорить не приходится. Действие закончено - и закончено безуспешно.

Хорошим признаком отличить одно от другого является проверка на возможность продолжить действие.

недоедать (голодать) – антоним: переедать
недоглядеть за больным (нельзя доглядеть за больным)
недосмотреть за ребенком (нельзя досмотреть за ребенком)

не доедать суп из-за спешки (можно потом доесть) 
не доглядеть спектакль (можно доглядеть в следующий раз)
не досмотреть фильм (можно вернуться и досмотреть его)

Примеры отсюда http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-138. Там же есть и обсуждение других правил на "не" с глаголом.

К сожалению, даже этот прием нельзя считать абсолютным. На самом-то деле "недо-" пишется слитно в силу того, что возникает новое действие, а не просто отрицание действия с "до-". Но это напрямую довольно сложно проверить, поэтому пользуются вышеназванными правилами, использующими косвенные признаки.

А вам, поскольку вы споткнулись на в общем-то простом случае, я бы в подобных случаях рекомендовал просто задуматься, а будет ли разным смысл при слитном и раздельном написании. Слитное написание обычно возникает, если если при раздельном будет другой смысл. Ну и когда без "не" глагол вообще не употребляется.

Answer (score 3):

1) Правильно: **не дотянем (не доживем) до пенсии.**

Дотянем до пенсии? ― Нет, не дотянем до пенсии. **Это отрицание, здесь только одно решение.**

2) **В других случаях приходится отличать НЕ+ДО от НЕДО.** Делать это желательно не подстановками, а **для каждого глагола   по его смыслу**.

**Существует два смысловых варианта:** (1)  довести/не довести действия до конца, (2) довести действие до полноты, до нормы, до указанного предела, до совершенства.

3) Некоторые глаголы имеют оба варианта, например: дети **не доели** кашу (оставили на тарелке) и дети постоянно **недоедают** (получают недостаточное питание).

4) Глагол ***дописать*** обычно пишется с НЕ раздельно (один смысловой вариант):

Секретарь вытаращил глаза на арестанта и **не дописал** слова. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Сколько у меня было рассказов и повестей, которых я **не дописал,** бросил. [А. И. Пантелеев. Наша Маша (1966)]

Я думаю, что Пуччини **не дописал** оперу не потому, что ему помешала смерть...(2002) // «Известия», 2002.07.25]

Но вот редкий вариант слитного написания:

Слова летописца: Еже ся где буду описал, или переписал, или **недописал**, чтите… а не кляните... Имеется в виду: можно написать лишнее, а можно не раскрыть тему.

5) О глаголе ***дотянуть*** (=достичь). У этого глагола тоже два смысла: **не дотянуть** до конкретного места, времени, предела, уровня (часто при наличии предлога ДО) и **недотягивать до совершенства** в обобщенном смысле.

Поэтому можно встретить **разные написания**: не дотянул до спортивной победы, до нормы,  до идеала, до пятерки в школе.

Но: До Моцарта все же **недотянул,** поскольку место было уже занято. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

..вдруг ни с того ни с сего  написал пять листов о Демьяне Бедном и опять мучаюсь ― все кажется, что чего-то **недотянул**, а может быть, и **перетянул**. [Виктор Астафьев. Зрячий посох (1978-1982)]

Надо сказать, что **качественная оценка с приставкой НЕДО** для глагола ***дотянуть*** встречается не так часто и может быть **авторским решением**.

**Из словаря:**

**ДОТЯНУТЬ** 5. до чего. Разг. Провести каким-л. образом время в ожидании начала, наступления чего-л. Не знаю, как д. до ужина.  // **Прожить, просуществовать** (обычно с трудом) до какого-л. срока, события; дожить. **Д. до пенсии.** 6. **до чего. Разг. Довести до определённого количества, уровня, степени совершенства.** Д. производительность труда до прежнего уровня. **Не дотянули двух процентов** до полного плана. **Д. рукопись молодого автора** (доработать, довести до нужного уровня).

**НЕДОДЯНУТЬ**, натянуть меньше, чем следует; **не достичь нужного уровня, результата.**

Answer (score 2):

**Не дотянем** до пенсии — так правильно.
Мне кажется, что Вы спутали два глагола.

[ДОТЯНУТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/52246); совер.
**5.** Пробыть, прожить в каком-нибудь состоянии до известного срока (разг.)
***Больной не дотянул до весны.***
**6.** *до чего*. Прожить, рассчитав свои расходы так, чтобы хватило до какого-нибудь срока (разг.). *Дотянуть до зарплаты.*

[НЕДОТЯНУТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/33332/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%CC%81%D1%82%D1%8C); *сов.; перех.*
**1.** Натянуть меньше, чем следует, требуется. *Недотянуть канат.*
**2.** *перен. разг.* Не выполнить в полном объеме того, что намечено, запланировано.

В словаре управления: недотянуть, **что**. *Недотянуть проволоку.*

*— С таким правлением мы, Любовь Михайловна, и **до пенсии не дотянем**!*
О. Таубе. Бесы

*— В этом месяце и **до половины не дотянем**, а твой табак сколько стоит.*
А. Деникин. Путь русского офицера

Answer (score 2):

Правильно (но только грамматически): **не дотянем до пенсии**.

Простой способ отличить приставку **недо-** от частицы **не** с глаголом такой: если предложение имеет смысл без **не**, тогда это частица. Этот способ работает почти во всех случаях.

**Примеры.**
Не дотянем до пенсии — дотянем до пенсии. (Оба выражения допустимы, следовательно **не** — частица).
Эти люди хронически недоедают — эти люди хронически доедают. (Второй вариант не имеет смысла, следовательно **недо-** — приставка.)

Comment: Признак хороший, но увы, не всегда работающий. Петя не()допил лекарство. бабушка не()довязала носок.